# Destination net unreachable, using two laptops and a router

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Using two laptops and a Router; OS Ubuntu.

First Laptop connected to router via Ethernet cable having gateway on eth0 192.168.10.1, and connected in adhoc wireless on wlan, IP 10.10.10.5.

configured:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Second one 10.10.10.4 is connected to 10.10.10.5 in adhoc wireless, 
also had the gateway is 10.10.10.5  UG in route -n.

```
sudo ip route add default via 10.10.10.5
```

When I ping 8.8.8.8 from Machine 10.10.10.4, it take infinite time and doesn't show any result of ping.

But, if the Ethernet is unplugged from the first laptop, it shows message from 10.10.10.5: "destination net unreachable".

From 10.10.10.5, its accessible directly.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try:

- Use tcpdump to see if packets are actually being sent and received. On Ubuntu, install and start tcpdump with "tcpdump -v icmp" to see ping packets, you can specify the interface with the -i Option. This will show you, if packets are received on eth0, and send on wlan0, maybe you can even do this on the 10.10.10.5 host, depending on what kind of device that is.
- Try "iptables -t nat -nvL" to see your iptables rules including packet and byte counters, so you can see if the rules are actually applied.

Both should give you greater insight where the packets arrive, and where they don't, so you can narrow down on where the problem is located.

Comment: got it, 
one more question, Can we give two routes to one PC?
so if one is not available the packet can be sent to other?